# how to change timestamp from lists of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dataframe, timestamp, list-comprehension

i have list of lists as

```
[[Timestamp('2022-04-06 11:56:39.951476'),
  'passed',
  '{"ref_price":44849.6333333333,"category":"by category 2","exe_time":"2022-04-06T12:02:44.836Z"}']]
```

How to change this to

```
[[Timestamp '2022-04-06 11:56:39.951476' ,
  'passed',
  '{"ref_price":44849.6333333333,"category":"by category 2","exe_time":"2022-04-06T12:02:44.836Z"}']]
```

Basically need to change the timestamp('time') to timestamp 'time'

How to achieve this.

Comment: Can you clarify? What type should be `Timestamp '2022-04-06 11:56:39.951476'`?

Comment: Is it possible to change the syntax alone with time type